# neo4j cypher query for csv import

Tags: neo4j

I am importing data from csv and using neo4j2.1.1. I use following query to find node with index....

LOAD CSV FROM `'file:/tmp/test.csv'` AS line Start

```
p = node:node_auto_index(mysqlPatientId = line[0])
set p.patDob = line[8]
return p;
```

But I tried a lot but always got error -------

```
SyntaxException: Invalid input 'l': expected whitespace, comment, "...string..." or a parameter (line 1, column 95)
"LOAD CSV FROM 'file:/tmp/10lpnew.csv' AS line Start p = node:node_auto_index(mysqlPatientId = line[0])"
```

thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Index lookups don't support expressions, only parameters and literal values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `LOAD CSV` does not play nicely with legacy indexes. Therefore I suggest to set a label on all nodes having a `mysqlPatientId`:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.mysqlPatientId) SET n :Patient
```

If you have a large number of these nodes, consider using SKIP and LIMIT to use a reasonable transaction size, e.g.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.mysqlPatientId) SET n :Patient SKIP 0 LIMIT 20000
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.mysqlPatientId) SET n :Patient SKIP 20000 LIMIT 20000
MATCH (n) WHERE HAS(n.mysqlPatientId) SET n :Patient SKIP 40000 LIMIT 20000
```

When done, create a schema index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Patient(mysqlPatientId)
```

Next is switching of auto indexing in `neo4j.properties`.

Importing CSV should no work like this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:/tmp/test.csv' AS line Start
MERGE (p:Patient { mysqlPatientId: line[0], patDob: line[8] })
```